# AJAX xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've been racking my brain for a few hours and can't figure out why a string comparison won't work.  In the following code, I do a xmlhttp call and get a response text.  The PHP file that I get a call IS returning the proper response string `"NOAD"`, and `NOAD` is being displayed when appropriate in my testing.  However, when the call is returned `NOAD` I want to identify it, however for some reason within the call below `xmlhttp.responseText == comparisonText` its NOT properly comparing the two.  Why does `xmlhttp.responseText` printout NOAD but I can't use it within the comparator?

```
function loadXMLAdImage1Doc(currentScenarioTime)
{

var returnText = "Not Here";
var comparisonText = "NOAD";

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{


    if (xmlhttp.responseText == comparisonText) 
       {
            document.getElementById("AJAXTEST").innerHTML =returnText;
       } else  {

            document.getElementById("AJAXTEST").innerHTML =xmlhttp.responseText; 
            }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So, you're saying that ``if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); ...`` prints out ``NOAD``?  There's no extra whitespace or anything?  Verified the string length?

Comment: There are no white spaces in the comparisionText (seen), and the xmlhttp.responseText doesn't show any white spaces.  I'll try verifying string length to see if there are any hidden characters, but it prints out in the innerHTML exactly as it should from the PHP file - "NOAD".  Which should in theory match the comparisonText...I think lol

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks Luth for pointing me in the right direction.  I solved my problem, but I'm not sure what the problem is within xmlhttp.responseText or user error that caused it.

The return text from my PHP file was placing an unseen character BEFORE the returned string (in testing, I would have figured it was an invisible character after prior to the results but go figure).  Theoretically, this shouldn't be happening...my PHP is returning a straightforward string:

```
..do some MYSQL queries..
$AdLink = mysql_result($result, 0);

if ($AdLink == "") {

echo "NOAD";
} else
{
echo $AdLink;
}
```

So the PHP file SHOULD be sending a 4 character return screen to the xmlhttp.responseText call named "NOAD".  But what was found in measuring the string length was that it was sending a 5 character string back with some invisible character BEFORE "NOAD" that wasn't showing up on the screen - therefore screwing up the comparator.  I used the following code to remove the character and it worked perfectly...

```
returnText = xmlhttp.responseText;
var returnlength = returnText.length;

returnText = returnText.substring(1, returnlength);
```

I have no idea WHAT the character is, whether its a problem with my PHP code or the xmlhttp.responseText call, but something to be aware of if you're dealing with the call.

Comment: It might be a BOM character (if you've changed the encoding of your file). What you can actually do to track it down, is use `headers_sent` function - it will give you an idea where the output has started.

Comment: A couple ideas:  1) You might be able to ``trim()`` your response to remove the hidden/whitespace characters, thus fixing your compare operation.  2) You can return a non-200 status from your PHP script (look at the ``header()`` function) for your NOAD status, and then handle that with a switch on ``xmlhttp.status``